# Local Variable and Private Variable relation

Tags: javascript

I know that local variable is related to the scope of function, meanwhile private variable is related to the way of accessing the variable itself....apart from that, I just want to confirm about local variable and private variable, I'm thinking that local variable can only accessed from specific place and can be accessed(example access a value) with specific "method"( example using return )

so is it true to say that a local variable can also considered as a private variable?

Comment: A "private variable" has no real meaning. Local variables in javascript are often used as a solution to enforce private *members*.

Comment: you can't access function varialble from outside

Comment: JS doesn't have private members(/fields/properties) on an object. The `this._foo` convention is often used to indicate private members, but doesn't actually provide any guarantee.

Comment: @ssube we often use a closure to hide as "local" variables the logical members we want to hide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **"private variable"** has no real meaning.

**Local variables** in closures are a common solution to enforce **private *members***.

Here's an example:

```
var counter = (function(){
  var count = 0;
  return {
    getCount: function(){
      return count;
    },
    increment: function(){
      count++;
    }
  }
})();

console.log(counter.getCount()); // 0
counter.increment();
console.log(counter.getCount()); // 1
console.log(counter.count);      // undefined, count is "private"
```